# Stored Procedure with SQL Injection

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to create a Stored Procedure that takes the IDs as inputs, and depending on the list of IDs will behave accordingly.

**Example:**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_G;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_G (
    IN  IDs VARCHAR(20) -- Example: '1, 2, 3'
    )
BEGIN
    SET @Query='SELECT * FROM table_users as t';

    IF IDs!=NULL
    THEN
        SET @Query=CONCAT(@Query, ' WHERE t.ID in(', IDs, ')'); -- SQL Injection problem
    END IF;

    PREPARE stmt FROM @Query;
    EXECUTE stmt;

END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

It happens that I have SQL injection in the ‘CONCAT’, because I can’t use the **'*EXECUTE stmt USING*' IDs** as is indicated on the following link:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

As the IDs parameter is optional, it will only influence the query when is not NULL. However, according to the documentation we assume that this ID parameter will always exist. If IDs parameter has SQL injection, will be executed.
Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you validate the input in the code that calls the procedure?

Comment: If you have anything above numbers and commas in the parameter, it's an attempt to inject sql.

Comment: @Barmar I try, but I'm afraid to forget in some place

Comment: @Shadow: Yes, but I can not guarantee that the input has only commas

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking and what you think an sql injection is, but I think you think you can't use prepare here because in one case you have no binding? You are of course allowed to put your two `prepare` and `execute` commands in the then-block and another execute in the else block (this time without prepare), `if... then ...set ... prepare... execute end else ... execute ... end;`. With varchar(20) as input, you might just want to accept 10 numbers as input, or generate 10 numbers from the input.

Comment: @Shadow: I Think that this is a problem: CALL sp_G('0\'); DROP TABLE table_users; -- ');

Comment: @Solarflare: I agree, but the problem is that I actually have a lot of stored procedures, and all of them have many optional parameters. In this example I simplified and only put a parameter.

(Number of IFs = 2^Number of optional parameters)

Comment: Well, it might be a surprise to you: the simplest solution is not always the safest one. I still don't really know what you are asking though. Do you want to know if someone can inject there? Yes. Do you want to know how to prevent it? Well, if you just give simplified examples, it is hard to answer in general, but a good idea would be:  do not say: "it is too much work to do it correctly".

Comment: @Solarflare: Im not good to speak English, but I will try to be clear: I know that someone can inject me. But I do not know how to protect myself. In this example I used one option parameter (IDs) in WHERE. But in reality I have many optional parameters that may or may not be concatenated to 'Query'. Exists some method to CONCAT parameters like parameters and not like strings? I have searched and can not find. I hope you understand me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression match to check that the parameter only contains allowed characters.

```
IF IDs IS NOT NULL AND IDs RLIKE '^[0-9, ]+$'
THEN
    SET @Query=CONCAT(@Query, ' WHERE t.ID in(', IDs, ')');
END IF
```

This works for a simple parameter like a list of IDs. It doesn't generalize to more complicated situations, though. The best solution is to design your application so you don't need to substitute user-provided input into the queries in the first place.

For instance, instead of a procedure that takes a comma-separated list of values to match against, the caller could put the information in a temporary table. Then the query would be

```
SELECT u.* FROM table_users AS u
JOIN temp_table AS t ON u.id = t.id
```